# Listing attribute values by frequency in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a simple question.

Let me show you the example fist.

If I have a matrix which is like below,

```
200  ,   2;
100  ,   4;
300  ,   6
```

(the first column is value and the second is counts of those value)

I want to array those data like below

```
200,200, 100,100, 100, 100, 300,300,300,300,300,300
```

How can I do that within MATLAB?

Comment: Have you tried [repelem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)?

Answer (score 1):

As [rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6579744/rahnema1) points out, this can be done using `repelem`. Following your example:

```
input = [200 2; 100 4; 300 6];
v = input(:,1); % your data
n = input(:,2); % these are your counts

result = repelem(v,n)

result = result'; % transpose result if preferred
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following matrix:

```
A = [   200  ,   2;
        100  ,   4;
        300  ,   6;]
```

You can do this:

```
B = repelem(A(:,1),A(:,2))';
```

And the output should be:

```
B =

   200   200   100   100   100   100   300   300   300   300   300   300
```